# how to know whether device /dev/hd* is a cdrom in linux with c/c++?

Tags: c++

I use xen to creae a vm and pass some information via virtual cdrom, finally, in DomU, I need to know which disk is the cdrom contains information.  The problem is : how can i find the cdrom device name？

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to execute lsblk, pipe in the result and in the result

```
sr0     11:0    1   308M  0 rom  
sda      8:0    0   120G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   300M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0 117.8G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
```

check for a line such as:

"rom" so, for me the CD-rom is /dev/sr0 . For you possibly it will be hd0

A little bit more work comes with using sysfs.h and the sysfs calls, more information is given in "man sysfs" or browsing the http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sysfs.h or the source of lsblk: http://gitorious.org/util-linux-ng/util-linux-ng/blobs/cc6b1d11eabf9d86849a80f2ca8b4c0afd45844f/misc-utils/lsblk.c

Hopefully this helps a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use content of /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/info

For example 
$ cat /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/info

```
CD-ROM information, Id: cdrom.c 3.20 2003/12/17
drive name:     sr0
drive speed:        62
drive # of slots:   1
Can close tray:     1
Can open tray:      1
Can lock tray:      1
Can change speed:   1
Can select disk:    0
Can read multisession:  1
Can read MCN:       1
Reports media changed:  1
Can play audio:     1
Can write CD-R:     1
Can write CD-RW:    1
Can read DVD:       1
Can write DVD-R:    1
Can write DVD-RAM:  1
Can read MRW:       1
Can write MRW:      1
Can write RAM:      1
```

Here, If "drive name:" line contain sr0, it 
means /dev/sr0 is cdrom.